# Complex version of Lax-Milgram Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I'm trying to prove Lax-Milgram Theorem in the complex case, i.e.

> Let $X$ be complex Hilbert space and let $f\in X'$, its topological dual. If $a(\cdot,\cdot):X\times X\to \mathbb{C}$ is sesquilinear bounded coercive form, then there exists a unique $u\in X$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
> a(u,v)=\langle f , v \rangle\qquad\forall\ v\in X.
> \end{equation}

I'm trying to proceed as in the real case. The only thing that differs is the statement of Riesz Representation Theorem. First of all, I rewrite the variational problem. By Riesz Representation Theorem there exists a unique $w\in X$ such that
\begin{equation}
\langle f, v \rangle =(v,w)_X\qquad\forall\ v\in X.
\end{equation}
We need to define a bounded linear bijection $A:X\to X$ such that
\begin{equation}
(v,w)_X=(v,Au)_X\qquad\forall\ v\in X,
\end{equation}
for a proper $u\in X$.
Any help?

Comment: May the statement of the theorem has to be rewritten as $$ a(u,v)=\overline{\langle f,v \rangle}\qquad\forall\ v\in X ? $$

Comment: @avaiti91 Hello, Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Library of Congress Cataloging-in-Publication Data
Lax, Peter D.
Functional analysis / Peter D. Lax.
p. cm.
Includes bibliographical references and index.
ISBN 0-471-55604-1 (cloth: alk. paper)
I. Functional analysis. I. Title.

Page 57, Theorem 6